# Android - removing Object from pageView results in blank space

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager

I'm about to program an app for controlling some LED-based gadgets around the house. To have multiply devices on one activity I used a page view with a view adapter to be able to select between the linked devices. Currently, I'm stuck with deleting views from the container. As soon as I delete the View, it disappears but leaves a blanc space inside my ViewPager as you can see in the picture below. I tried everything suggested by other users, like returning

> POSITION_NONE

when overwriting the

> getItemPosition

method. I provide you with the code of my pageViewAdapter. I hope someone can suggest a solution to that problem. I'm very stuck here.

```
package com.example.fabsinnenraumgestaltung;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CardPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements CardAdapter {

ViewPager viewPager;
MainActivity mainActivity;

private List<CardView> mViews;
private List<CardItem> mData;
private float mBaseElevation;

public CardPagerAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ViewPager viewPager) {
    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    mViews = new ArrayList<>();
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    this.viewPager = viewPager;
}

public void addCardItem(CardItem item) {
    mViews.add(null);
    mData.add(item);
}

public float getBaseElevation() {
    return mBaseElevation;
}

@Override
public CardView getCardViewAt(int position) {
    return mViews.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
    mData.set(position, null);
    mViews.set(position, null);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Button deleteButton;
    Button editButton;

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.device_card_layout, container, false);

    deleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    editButton = view.findViewById(R.id.editButton);

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("delete");
            deleteCardOperation(viewPager.getCurrentItem(), container);

        }
    });

    editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("edit");
            int currentCard = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        }
    });

    container.addView(view);
    bind(mData.get(position), view);
    CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemCard);

    if (mBaseElevation == 0) {
        mBaseElevation = cardView.getCardElevation();
    }



    cardView.setMaxCardElevation(mBaseElevation * MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR);
    mViews.set(position, cardView);

    return view;
}





private void bind(CardItem item, View view) {
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
    TextView ipTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemIPAdress);
    TextView statusView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemActiveStatus);
    titleTextView.setText(item.getName());
    ipTextView.setText(item.getIp());
    statusView.setText(item.getStatus());


}

private void deleteCardOperation(int cardIndicator, ViewGroup desV){


    CardItem x = mData.get(cardIndicator);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    builder.setTitle("Confirm");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this device: "+ x.getName() + " ?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            destroyItem(desV, cardIndicator, getCardViewAt(cardIndicator));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}

private void editCard(){

}




}
```

[image]

I really hope you can help. Thanks.

First edit:

I edited my code as Michiel suggested. I now call a deleteCardItem() method to remove the data from my dataset like shown below.

```
public void deleteCardItem(int position){
    mData.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

With notifyDatasetChanged beeing called, the system takes over and calls getItemPosition(). Ive edited this method as well like Michiel suggested.

```
@Override
 public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    //return super.getItemPosition(object);

    int position = mData.indexOf(object);

    if(position == -1){
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }else{
        return position;
    }


}
```

Problem now is, that i can not compare the given "object" with any dataset, because "object" is a View object and mData is my Arraylist aka dataset. That leads to a starnge behaviour in my app.
The card will not disapear anymore. It is shown but the data is deleted.
I would appreciate further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully destroy the view itself you should try to write `destroyItem` like this:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
        mViews.set(position, null);
}
```

So the View object is fully destroyed.
And also try to set the View to null in `deleteCardItem`

```
@Override
public void deleteCardItem(int position){
        mData.remove(position);
        mViews.set(position, null);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And also try to search for the View instead of the Data inside of `getItemPosition`.

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        int position = mViews.indexOf(object);
        if(position == -1){
                return POSITION_NONE;
        }else{
                return position;
        }
}
```

After that, you don't see them anymore

Comment: I tried to implement your solution. Thank you very much, this worked very well for me. It seems to be a similar problem as i thought.

Answer (score 1):

I see mainly three problems. First, you see a blank space, because the item is not removed; instead, it is set to null. When in `destroyItem()`, `mData.set(position, null);` is called, the resulting array will be as `[(CardItem), null, (CardView)]`. The size of this array is still 3. The solution: call `mData.remove(position)`.

Second, it is the responsibility of `PagerAdapter` to call all the functions annotated with `@Override`. When you call `notifyDatasetChanged()`, it will call `destroyItem()`. You should change `mData`, call `notifyDatasetChanged()` and let the `PagerAdapter` do its' job. It will remove the view itself and call `destroyItem()` for you, so you can do additional cleaning, such as removing the view from `mView`.

Third, if this is just a one time project you can leave this be. However, if it is a long term project, you could look into fi. [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) or other design principles. An examples: your PagerAdapter should do 1 thing and one thing only. It should only connect your dataset mData with your views, know it also handles updating mData, showing the dialog and more. Another example: your reference to MainActivity can be replaced by Context; the code would still work, but can be used in other activities or fragments without any added work.

TL;DR:

```
// This is called by the PagerAdapter itself
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    mViews.remove(position);
}

// Call this when the user taps yes
private void deletePage(int position) {
    mData.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your huge explanation. It just made me understand,  that the destroyItem() method is called by notifyDatasetChanged(). I just implemented those things the way you suggested, but that led to a very strange behaviour of the View. I try to explain. The Card does not get deleted anymore. It is still shown. I just debugged the whole thing with breakpoints on the destroyItem() method and noticed that the method is not called when i call notifyDatasetChanged().

Comment: I noticed another strange behaviour. The data gets in fact removed but the view does not. The cards are all there, but i can't scroll to the last of them. Am I right with my thought that the destroyItem() method is in fact not called ?

Comment: As i found out, the destroyItem() method will only get called, when the getItemPosition() method returns POSITION_NONE. If it returns an Object, destroyItem() will not be called. The problem is, that exactly does not happen. I only get Objects back from the getItemPosition method. My question now is how i can exactly change that. The documentation says, that "super.getItemPosition(object)" will normally return both, an object OR in fact null. But in my case it seems not to work. Do you have any further suggestion for me how i can solve this? Or any Idea what could also be the problem?

Comment: You are right.  The solution is to implement `getItemPosition()` yourself, something like: `int position = mData.indexOf(object); if (position == -1) return POSITION_NONE; else return position;

Comment: At the moment im trying to figure out how i can implement your solution. If i get you right, i should compare the data with the views to recognize what is missing and then return -1 to delete the corresponding view in the Process. Due to the fact, that "object" will give you a CardView object and nothing you can compare mData with, the operation will always return false results. Because i can not compare a View Object with a "custom" object this operation will fail and `int position = mData.indexOf(object); always return -1 for every card. That leads to an exception. I have to fix that first.